# How do I turn ON the new Google Groups Interface?

Tags: google-groups

I'm not able to set the new Google Groups interface ON. I had it a couple of weeks ago, but for some reason I'm back to the old interface...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is obsolete. Google have launched another new version the is no option to turn on / off the new interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a notification bar prompting you to switch to the new version, but I don't see anything in settings menu.

Try going to [this overview page](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!overview), it should open the new groups interface and have a bar asking you to set that as default.